# SOAP upsert() is failing on the Order - INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE

Tags: soap-api

I am making an upsert call using SOAP UI on the order object. But I am facing below error.

```
<message>Unable to create/update fields: PricebookEntryId. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.</message>
<statusCode>INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE</statusCode>
```

Now if i delete the records from my org and the make upsert it worked fine but again when I again make upsert on that record it will fail by showing above error message.

Then I tried to remove the below code from the wsdl and upsert worked.

```
<urn:PricebookEntry xsi:type="PricebookEntry"> 
<urn:EXT_PricebookEntry_ID__c>demoid</urn:EXT_PricebookEntry_ID__c> 
</urn:PricebookEntry>
```

How can I fix this without removing the above code. Please advicce.

Thanks
Ashu

Comment: What happens if you try the same upsert via anonymous apex or the web UI?

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Any logic that performs an update to the PricebookEntryId when the EXT_PricebookEntry_ID__c is populated?  Sound like the user profile doesn't have the proper permission to update this field.  Maybe this logic is only firing on updates not insert?